# Transversality Condition

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, open-economy-macro

I am reading the first section of chapter 10 of the Obstfeld and Rogoff textbook *Foundations of International Economics* and I have a doubt in how the transversality condition is obtained. Even though there is a footnote saying that it is obtained by iterating the period budget constraint, after trying a little bit I still cannot get it.

The period budget constraint is given by:

$$P_tB^j_{t+1}+M^j_t=P_t(1+r_t)B^j_t+M^j_{t-1}+p_t(j)y_t(j)-P_tC^j_t-P_t\tau_t$$

where the transversality condition is:

$$\lim_{T\to\infty} R_{t,t+T}\bigg(B_{t+T+1}+\frac{M_{t+T}}{P_{t+T}}\bigg)=0$$

Could someone please shed some light on how to start iterating the budget constraint in order to obtain the TVC?

Thank you